# Android displayJSON data

Tags: android, json, textview

I need to display some JSON data on an android app but I don't know how to do.

Example of JSON data

```
{
name: name,
surname: surname,
history: [{date: date, job: job}, {date: date, job: job}]
}
```

I want to show the list of job and date

```
String[] data = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.userData);

<TextView android:text="Date" />
<TextView android:text="@+id/job" />
<TextView android:text="Job" />
<TextView android:text="@+id/date" />


TextView job= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.job);
job.setText(??);
```

But I don't know how to set the data to the TextView

Thank you

Comment: use [gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to ease your work, user-guide [here](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide).

it will be easy.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the `org.json` library. It will allow you to parse and process your JSON as a `JSONObject`. Inside that you'll have two strings and a `JSONArray`, which you can also drill down into.

The library makes it all very easy.

Once you have your `JSONObject obj`, call

```
obj.getJSONArray("history");
```

to get the next level down; then iterate through that, looking at the objects it contains, on each one calling

```
historyElt.getString("job");
```